# How to hide views in layout editor using data binding in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-databinding

I am using data binding in my xml layout, I need to hide some views when user click on a button and its working perfectly fine.

Problem is that I need to place other views to places where hidden views were placed. But while editing layout in layout editor its showing all the layouts. How can I force editor to hide all those views that are bind with dynamic visibility, so I can place new views.

Here is what i am doing in my layout

```
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="isInEditState"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>
```

this is how I set visibility which is working fine when I run app

```
android:visibility="@{isInEditState ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

Comment: use tools:visibilty="gone" , and if you are using to hide multiple view in one action and show than the best approach to use Group in ContsrantLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tools:visibility="invisible"` or `tools:visibility="gone"` to the views whose visibility is bound to databinding to not to show up in the layout editor

Ps: On adding this attribute if you get any error, just add the required namespace(`toolsNs`) by pressing `alt+enter`